# SSH asks for passphrase for some keys despite being added to agent

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, public-key

I have two servers where I connect using SSH public key authentication, with different keys. The configuration looks like this:

```
Host server1
  IdentityFile /path/to/key
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host server2
  IdentityFile /path/to/other/key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I add the two keys to the agent and verify via `ssh-add -l` that both are present. Yet, one works but the other does not:

```
$ssh -v server1
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /path/to/key
debug1: Server accepts key: ...
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).

$ssh -v server2
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /path/to/other/key
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/path/to/other/key':
```

The OS is Ubuntu 14.04, the output of `ssh -V` is `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`.

Comment: are you sure key for host2 is okay ? **debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker**

Comment: I can log in with it after typing the passphrase.

Comment: @Jakuje to quote from the question, *I add the two keys to the agent and verify via `ssh-add -l` that both are present.*

Comment: Sorry. My bad. What are the types? Normal `RSA` in openssh format or some `pem`? There must be some difference.

Comment: What's a reliable way to determine that? They certainly look like normal keys - `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, some properties, a big block of base64 data, `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.